# Running pod install: "Invalid Podfile file: undefined method use_native_modules!"

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got an Expo project that I'm trying to add custom code to.

I'm following this tutorial:

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

But when I run either `npx expo run:ios` or `pod install` in the /ios folder, I get this:

```
⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `use_native_modules!' for
#<Pod::Podfile:0x0000000108ca7ed0 @defined_in_file=#<Pathname:/Users/john/
Documents/GitHub/app2/ios/Podfile>, @internal_hash={"installation_method"=
{"name"=>"cocoapods", "options"=>{:deterministic_uuids=>false}}}, 
@root_target_definitions=[#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>], 
@current_target_definition=#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>>
Did you mean?  use_expo_modules!.

 #  from /Users/john/Documents/GitHub/app-2/ios/Podfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    use_expo_modules!
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I can't seem to find any solutions online that are helping to fix this.

What's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Ended up deleting the `/ios` folder and following the steps here:

https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Specifically:

```
npx install-expo-modules@latest
```

Seemed to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

It can be one of two.

You did not install the pods or you are trying to use expo and this conflicts with your application.

try with `cd ios/ && pod install`

Comment: I tried that, same message